# Running in-memory elasticMQ in Java

Tags: java, testing, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to get an embedded SQS mock going for some self-contained local testing of a Java SQS client.

ElasticMQ sounds like it should do what I'm after, but the instructions seem to assume I'm using Java, and I can't figure out how to start ElasticMQ's rest server from within Java.

I've tried what I assume is the Java equivalent of the code provided at https://github.com/adamw/elasticmq#starting-an-embedded-elasticmq-server-with-an-sqs-interface:

```
RestServer server = new SQSRestServerBuilder().start()
```

but SQSRestServerBuilder() expects a `Client` parameter, and I have no idea what to put in there.

Has anyone else got ElasticMQ running in-memory in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of `SQSRestServerBuilder` does not seem to require a `Client` parameter.  Are you using an older version of ElasticMQ?

see https://github.com/adamw/elasticmq/blob/master/rest/rest-sqs/src/main/scala/org/elasticmq/rest/sqs/SQSRestServerBuilder.scala

If you are using an older version, you can create an in memory SQS server by doing something like this:

```java
import org.elasticmq.Node
import org.elasticmq.NodeBuilder
import org.elasticmq.rest.RestServer
import org.elasticmq.rest.sqs.SQSRestServerBuilder
import org.elasticmq.storage.inmemory.InMemoryStorage

...

Node node = NodeBuilder.withStorage(new InMemoryStorage())
RestServer sqsServer = new SQSRestServerBuilder(node.nativeClient()).start()
```

The above code is a specific example for ElasticMQ 0.6.3, which relies on Scala 2.10.